# You want/expect me to believe that?

Tags: idiomatic-language

**Woman:** *What are you doing here?*

**Man:** *Nothing.*

**Woman:** *You expect me to believe that? You slept with her, didn't you?*

My question is if I could use 'want' in place of 'expect' and it would be just as natural in the context? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Want* and *Expect* can mean two different things.  In your sentence *want* and *expect* can be freely substituted.  In the passionate context of confronting a cheating lover, the meaning of the sentence remains the same, *I don't believe your lies*. It would sound natural to hear either.

Comment: @SandipKumarMandal - Entirely incorrect and off base.  You are completely missing the point, failing to see the forest through the trees.  They mean the same in the given context.  When 'woman' says *You expect/want me to believe that*, she is saying, *I think you are lying*.  Whether she uses *expect* or *want* to express her suspicion of deception does not change the meaning.